# Generating a subspace sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Say *X* is a set and $\mathcal{E}$ is a collection of its subsets.

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the sigma-algebra generated by $\mathcal{E}$ (or the smallest sigma-algebra over *X* containing all members of $\mathcal{E}$)

Provide the subset $Y \subset X$ the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{M}^* = \{ M \cap Y : M \in \mathcal{M}\}$. Analogously define the collection $\mathcal{E}^* = \{E \cap Y : E \in \mathcal{E}\}$ of subsets of *Y*.

Is it true that $\mathcal{E}$* generates $\mathcal{M}$* (that $\mathcal{M}$* is the smallest sigma-algebra over *Y* containing $\mathcal{E}$*)?

EDIT:
So I found a solution. The answer is yes. It involved taking  the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{N}^*$ over *Y* actually generated by $\mathcal{E}^*$ and constructing the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{N}$ over *X* consisting of all subsets of *X* whose intersection with *Y* was a member of $\mathcal{N}^*$, noticing that $\mathcal{N}$ contained $\mathcal{E}$ and therefore contains $\mathcal{M}$, and deducing that $\mathcal{N}^* \supset \mathcal{M}^*$. The reverse inclusion is easy.

Comment: The intersection symbol (and much else) can be displayed by putting dollar signs around an expression, triggering `MathJax` to display $\LaTeX$ syntax as mathematics.  For example, `M \cap Y` becomes $M \cap Y$.  Some introduction is [here for notation help](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: What happens when you try to prove it?

Comment: I keep applying the $\sigma$ operator which sends a collection of sets to the collection of countable unions of its members, or the $\delta$ operator defined analogously, with intersections in place of unions, to try and express the actual algebra generated by **E*** as something like **E*** $_{\sigma \delta \sigma \cdots}$

Comment: This iterative process is definitely not the most convenient one to approach generated sigma-algebras (note that, on the real line R, starting from the open sets and taking successively complements, countable unions, and countable intersections, it requires uncountably many iterations before one gets B(R) the Borel sigma-algebra). You must know another characterization of the sigma-algebra generated by a collection of subsets, no?

Comment: Sorry for the change of font. I decided to go with calligraphy

Answer (score 2):

The $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}^{\ast}$ can be viewed as the initial
$\sigma$-algebra generated by the inclusion map.

More precisely, let $i:Y\rightarrow X$ be the inclusion map defined
by $i(x)=x$. We can verify that $\mathcal{M}^{\ast}$ is the smallest
$\sigma$-algebra on $Y$ such that $i$ is $\mathcal{M^{\ast}}/\mathcal{M}$-measurable
and $\mathcal{M^{\ast}}$is explicitly given by $\mathcal{M}^{\ast}=i^{-1}(\mathcal{M}):=\{i^{-1}(B)\mid B\in\mathcal{M}\}$.
Also note that $\mathcal{E}^{\ast}=i^{-1}(\mathcal{E})$. In the following,
we show that $\sigma\left(i^{-1}(\mathcal{E})\right)=i^{-1}\left(\sigma(\mathcal{E})\right)$.

Since $\mathcal{E}\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{E})$, we have $i^{-1}(\mathcal{E})\subseteq i^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{E}))$.
Observe that $i^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{E}))$ is a $\sigma$-algebra,
so $\sigma\left(i^{-1}(\mathcal{E})\right)\subseteq i^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{E}))$.

To show the reverse inclusion $i^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{E}))\subseteq\sigma\left(i^{-1}(\mathcal{E})\right)$,
we let $\mathcal{N}=\{B\subseteq X\mid i^{-1}(B)\in\sigma\left(i^{-1}(\mathcal{E})\right)\}$.
By direct verification, $\mathcal{N}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$
and $\mathcal{E}\subseteq\mathcal{N}$. Therefore $\sigma(\mathcal{E})\subseteq\mathcal{N}$
and hence $i^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal{E}))\subseteq\sigma\left(i^{-1}(\mathcal{E})\right)$.

We remark that the theorem $\sigma\left(i^{-1}(\mathcal{E})\right)=i^{-1}\left(\sigma(\mathcal{E})\right)$
continues to hold if $Y$ is replaced by an arbitrary set and $i$
is replaced by an arbitrary map $f:Y\rightarrow X$.